# Authentication issue with Reddit bot

Tags: python, python-2.7, reddit, praw

I am having an issue creating a Reddit session via my script for a bot. I have installed praw via pip and have created a praw.ini file in the same directory as my bot script:

```
[DEFAULT]
# A boolean to indicate whether or not to check for package updates.
check_for_updates=True

# Object to kind mappings
comment_kind=t1
message_kind=t4
redditor_kind=t2
submission_kind=t3
subreddit_kind=t5

# The URL prefix for OAuth-related requests.
oauth_url=https://oauth.reddit.com

# The URL prefix for regular requests.
reddit_url=https://www.reddit.com

# The URL prefix for short URLs.
short_url=https://redd.it

[bot1]
client_id=clientId
client_secret=clientSecret
password=myPassword
username=myUsername
user_agent=My bot description
```

I have verified the praw.ini file is using the correct client ID/secret. I've also upgraded to Python 2.7.14 to see if that resolves any errors as well, but when I run the following script:

```py
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')

print(reddit.user.me())
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myBot.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(reddit.user.me())
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\praw\models\user.py", line 60, in me
    user_data = self._reddit.get(API_PATH['me'])
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 367, in get
    data = self.request('GET', path, params=params)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 472, in request
    params=params)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 181, in reques
t
    params=params, url=url)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 124, in _reque
st_with_retries
    retries, saved_exception, url)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 90, in _do_ret
ry
    params=params, url=url, retries=retries - 1)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 124, in _reque
st_with_retries
    retries, saved_exception, url)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 90, in _do_ret
ry
    params=params, url=url, retries=retries - 1)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 112, in _reque
st_with_retries
    data, files, json, method, params, retries, url)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 97, in _make_r
equest
    params=params)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\rate_limit.py", line 32, in call
    kwargs['headers'] = set_header_callback()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 141, in _set_h
eader_callback
    self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 328, in refresh
    password=self._password)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 138, in _request_t
oken
    response = self._authenticator._post(url, **data)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 29, in _post
    data=sorted(data.items()))
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prawcore\requestor.py", line 49, in reques
t
    raise RequestException(exc, args, kwargs)
prawcore.exceptions.RequestException: error with request ("bad handshake: Error(
[('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')
],)",)
```

Posts on Stack Overflow that are seemingly related indicate that it is a problem with the authentication for my script, but after verifying that I'm using the correct credentials and regenerating the client ID and secret I'm still not getting past this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been an issue with my installation of Python. I fixed this by running `pip install python-certifi-win32`.